# Windows form drag control

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to make a windows form that is similar in the UI to winscp or norton commander where there are two lists of DB selections and the ability to drag and drop multiple items from one list to
the other.
Which .net control do you recommend?
Thanks

Comment: Instead of using some third party control, you can think of writing your own. Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984430(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I think ListView with detail view should be fine.

Comment: Thanks Parkash but i need to do it fast and why writing something on your own when there is a good control that has been tested for free.

Comment: Please refer to [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/DragDropListBox.aspx) article.

Answer (score -1):

There is a property to allow draganddrop, and an event you can subscribe to,
Then you can get infirmation on what is dropped, usimeg the eventargs